# Rotating Sprite with Touch - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Does anyone have a better way to rotate a sprite with one finger?  My problem is that I can not get the sprite to stop rotating after it has been fully rotated twice and I flip my screen 180 degree periodcally (self.rotation = 180;) then flip it back (self.rotation = 0).  But, when I flip it to 180 degrees the sprite will not rotate properly.

Any one have any better ideas than this?

```
CGFloat gRotation;

- (void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    g.rotation = gRotation;
}
    - (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(g.boundingBox, location))
        {
            CGPoint firstLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

            CGPoint touchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
            CGPoint firstTouchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:firstLocation];

            CGPoint firstVector = ccpSub(firstTouchingPoint, g.position);
            CGFloat firstRotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(firstVector);
            CGFloat previousTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(firstRotateAngle);

            CGPoint vector = ccpSub(touchingPoint, g.position);
            CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(vector);
            CGFloat currentTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotateAngle);

            gRotation += currentTouch - previousTouch;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

***EDIT:***

I went in to GameConfig.h and changed `#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController` to `#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone`

Then, went in to AppDelegate.m and changed `#if  GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController` to `#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationNone`

That fixed the sprite's rotation when I flipped the screen, but I am still having problems stopping the sprite's rotation after two full rotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a new line at the end:

```
gRotation += currentTouch - previousTouch;
gRotation = fmod(gRotation,360.0); // <<< fix the angle
```

this maybe fix your problem, because the angle will stay in the 360 range

Other way to rotate with one finger is the UIPanGestureRecognizer (but you still need to keep the angle in the 360 range):

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:layer action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)] autorelease];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

...

- (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
  ...
}
```

Take a look at this tutorial for more details (its on drag, but show how to do the pan gesture):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d

Comment: is there a different way to spin the sprite though? Because, the grinderRotation degrees depend on the currentTouch and previousTouch

Comment: you could use a UIPanGestureRecognizer class to detect a drag with only one finger (iOS 4 or better).

Comment: Isn't UIPanGestureRecognizer more for animations? I need the sprite to rotate while you are moving your finger then when you lift your finger it stops. The sprite also needs to rotate as fast or as slow as your finger does

Comment: is just it. The Pan Recognizer give the amount of move while the user drag the finger on screen - its not about animation, its about touch interface